# Grouped bar chart for categories by month/year

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

I'm trying to use Plotly to create a stacked or grouped bar chart that has month/year on the x-axis and values on the y-axis. The data frame looks like this:

```
category     value   date
apple        4       10/2020
banana       3       10/2020
apple        2       10/2020
strawberry   1       11/2020
banana       4       11/2020
apple        9       11/2020
banana       4       12/2020
apple        7       12/2020
strawberry   4       12/2020
banana       8       12/2020
.
.
.
```

Assuming that newer dates will come through, and also more categories can be added, I'm trying to create a grouped bar chart that is also scrollable on the x-axis(date).

I tried this to create the grouped bar chart but it ends up being a stacked bar chart instead:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig_3_a = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(
                    x=df['date'],
                    y=df['value'],
                    text=df['category'],
                    textposition='auto', 
                    orientation ='v',
                    )],
                    layout=go.Layout(barmode='group'))
```

I would like something like this instead, where the different categories can possibly be assigned a different color, and the x-axis being the month/day and the y-axis being the value. Here, `gender==category` and `x-axis==month/year`. Also would need to add the scrolling for the x-axis to see all the month/year:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it simply with `plotly.express`.

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(df, x='date', y='value', color='category', barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

If you want to do it with `go.Bar` class, you need to add traces for each category.

[image]